# MVC 3 _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, razor

I'm creating an MVC 3 application and hosting it in IIS 7 as I'm tired of spinning up Cassini for debugging. My problem is w/ the layout 1) Whenever I use the layout attribute on the individual views I get an error page stating that the specific page can't be found, 2) I don't have an option to add specifically add a _ViewStart.cshtml from add new item. I'm at a lost, either my installation is botched or I need to upgrade my IIS or both. Any ideas so I can start using my Layouts?

Comment: Have you looked into developing with IIS Express instead of Cassini?

Comment: I'm using IIS 7 instead of Cassini this time around